# How to use assertion with test while executing tests in testlink

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testlink

I am creating test in selenium with java and using testlink for test execution and result.Without assertion tests are working fine with testlink and showing result but when I am using assertion to verify expected and actual result like this:

```
try {

        driver.get("http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com");     
        String ExpextedTitle="Software testing tutorials and automatio";
        String ActualTitle=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='title']")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(ActualTitle, ExpextedTitle);
        IntegrationWithTestLink.updateResult("GR-1", null, TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED);
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Hiiiii");
         IntegrationWithTestLink.updateResult("GR-1", e.getMessage(), TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED);
     }
 }
```

I don't know why result are not showing in testlink in case for 
       exception. Can anyone suggest me better approach to use Assertion here.

Comment: What is your `ActualTitle` & `ExpextedTitle`?

Comment: My ActualTitle & ExpextedTitle is : "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" There is some problem while working with assertion.

Comment: this link http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testlink-tutorial-3/ may help you

Comment: @Murthi Thanks for sharing link but problem is that after getting exception in try block , catch block is not executing.Please check edited question code.

Comment: is it printing the text "Hiiiii"?

Comment: are you using junit or testng?

Comment: No,I am getting Exception AssertionError: expected [Software testing tutorials and automatio] but found [Software testing tutorials and automation] ,but it is going inside catch block to handle this.

Comment: I am using testng here

Comment: AssertionError is not a Exception. so it will not be caught by catch block because, you are capturing only exception. please change catch block as catch(AssertionError e){ //your code} it will catch your error.

Comment: Thanks Murthi for clarification now it's working fine.But I have one more doubt now I am getting failed test in test link but it's showing test as pass in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assertion Error is not caught by catch block as your are catching exception not the error. To catch the Error change the code as given below.

try {

```
    driver.get("http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com");     
    String ExpextedTitle="Software testing tutorials and automatio";
    String ActualTitle=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='title']")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(ActualTitle, ExpextedTitle);
    IntegrationWithTestLink.updateResult("GR-1", null, TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED);
 }catch(AssertionError e){
     System.out.println("Hiiiii");
     IntegrationWithTestLink.updateResult("GR-1", e.getMessage(), TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED);
 }
```

}

It may work for you.

Comment: Thanks Murthi for clarification now it's working fine.But I have one more doubt now I am getting failed test in test link but it's showing test as pass in Eclipse.

Comment: because you are catch the error. you can print a message failed.